Splitting a checkered figure into boundary squares
A cell on the plane is a unit square with integer vertices. Let $A$ be a finite cellular figure (a finite union of cells).
Is it true that $A$ can always be partitioned onto (cellular) squares $B_i$, none of which is contained in the interior of $A$?
At this point, I believe the statement is true, but the induction does not work for me.

I'm still not getting it.  I assume that a "boundary point" is one such that at least one of its four neighbors isn't in the set?  if so, consider the set $A$ with five points, $A={(0,0), (0, \pm 1), (\pm 1,0)}$.  Then, $(0,0)$ is not a boundary point, but the other four are, right?  So...how would you cover that with squares?  There is no non-trivial square in $A$, but you can't use one point squares as the one at $(0,0)$ would not intersect the boundary.  What am I misunderstanding?

@lulu Think of $\mathbb Z^2$ as a chessboard. Each element of $\mathbb Z^2$ is a unit square. The goal is partition $A$ into subregions, where each subregion is square-shaped, and each subregion contains at least one boundary square of $A$. A boundary square of $A$ is a square that is corner-adjacent to a square in the complement of $A$.

@MikeEarnest  Ah, thank you.  That makes sense.   Sticking to my picture, I get the same problem if I include the "diagonal" neighbors, yes?  That is to say, in my  $A$, the origin is in fact a boundary point as, for instance, $(1,1)\not \in A$.

Yes, it is important here that any cell has 8 neighbors: 4 on the side and 4 on the corner.

I edited the question, hope that it is clear now. Looks interesting for me.

Spillner, A. (2006). Minimum boundary touching tilings of polyominoes. MLQ, 52(1), 29–36.
The answer is yes, and in this article the author explored optimal methods for finding a partition.
